# Add a cut-run-paste shortcut to gnome shortcuts

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, text-processing

I have a program that gets text from the clipboard, does some operations on it and returns it to the clipboard. Then, the program shuts down.

Can I make a shortcut ---like a gnome keyboard shortcut, context menu item, etc.--- for it that cuts selected text, runs my program and pastes the text? Or do you have any other solution for this?

The shortcut/operation should work all over Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Make a script:
(open gedit and paste this, then save)

```
#!/bin/bash

xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+x        # This should cut the text

sleep 1       # We need to give time to clipboard really get the text, you can try lower values like .5

/path/to/your/program   # Put the path to your program here

sleep 1

xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+v      # This should paste the text

exit 0
```

2) Make it executable (chmod +x /path/to/script).

3) Launch the Keyboard configuration `gnome-control-center keyboard`:
(Go to Shortcuts → Custom shortcuts)

[image]

4) Click on "+"  and add a name and the command:

```
    /path/to/script
```

5) Choose the key binding that you want.

6) Because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1243532), you will have to logout and log back in so the shortcut can take effect.